# Adding Multiple Values to a Variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix

I have to work with a lot of data and run the same MATLAB program more than once, and every time the program is run it will store the data in the same preset variables. The problem is, every time the program is run the values are overwritten and replaced, most likely because all the variables are type double and are not a matrix. I know how to make a variable that can store multiple values in a program, but only when the program is run once.

This is the code I am able to provide:

```
volED = reconstructVolume(maskAlignedED1,maskAlignedED2,maskAlignedED3,res)
volMean = (volED1+volED2+volES3)/3

strokeVol = volED-volES
EF = strokeVol/volED*100
```

The program I am running depends on a ton more MATLAB files that I cannot provide at this moment, however I believe the double variables strokeVol and EF are created at this instant. How do I create a variable that will store multiple values and keep adding the values every time the program is run?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Is this a MATLAB function called interactively? Or is it a standalone code run outside MATLAB? Anyway, your `volES` variable is undefined in your excerpt. If I understand correctly, you probably need to define a vector containing the output you want to save, and you have to update that (by giving it as also input variable to your function) and return from your program with each run.

Comment: I added an answer based on my best guesses, but feel free to revise your question in order to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your variables are "overwritten" with each run is that every function (or standalone program) has its own workspace where the local variables are located, and these local variables cease to exist when the function (or standalone program) returns/terminates. In order to preserve the value of a variable, you have to return it from your function. Since MATLAB passes its variables by value (rather than reference), you have to explicitly provide a vector (or more generally, an array) as input and output from your function if you want to have a cumulative set of data in your calling workspace. But it all depends on whether you have a function or a deployed program.

### Assuming your program is a function

If your function is now declared as something like

```
function strokefraction(inputvars)
```

you can change its definition to

```
function [EFvec]=strokefraction(inputvars,EFvec)
%... code here ...
%volES initialized somewhere
volED = reconstructVolume(maskAlignedED1,maskAlignedED2,maskAlignedED3,res);
volMean = (volED1+volED2+volES3)/3;

strokeVol = volED-volES;
EF = strokeVol/volED*100;  

EFvec = [EFvec; EF]; %add EF to output (column) vector
```

Note that it's legal to have the same name for an input and an output variable. Now, when you call your function (from MATLAB or from another function) each time, you add the vector to its call, like this:

```
EFvec=[]; %initialize with empty vector
for k=1:ndata %simulate several calls
   inputvar=inputvarvector(k); %meaning that the input changes
   EFvec=strokefraction(inputvar,EFvec);
end
```

and you will see that the size of `EFvec` grows from call to call, saving the output from each run. If you want to save several variables or arrays, do the same (for arrays, you can always introduce an input/output array with one more dimension for this purpose, but you probably have to use explicit indexing instead of just shoving the next `EF` value to the bottom of your vector).

Note that if your input/output array eventually grows large, then it will cost you a lot of time to keep allocating the necessary memory by small chunks. You could then choose to allocate the `EFvec` (or equivalent) array instead of initializing it to `[]`, and introduce a counter variable telling you where to overwrite the next data points.

Disclaimer: what I said about the workspace of functions is only true for local variables. You could also define a `global EFvec` in your function and on your workspace, and then you don't have to pass it in and out of the function. As I haven't yet seen a problem which actually needed the use of `global` variables, I would avoid this option. Then you also have `persistent` variables, which are basically `global`s with their scope limited to their own workspace (run `help global` and `help persistent` in MATLAB if you'd like to know more, these help pages are surprisingly informative compared to usual help entries).

### Assuming your program is a standalone (deployed) program

While I don't have any experience with standalone MATLAB programs, it seems to me that it would be hard to do what you want for that. [A MathWorks Support answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92537-how-do-i-pass-arguments-into-and-out-of-my-standalone-executable) suggests that you *can* pass variables to standalone programs, but only as you would pass to a shell script. By this I mean that you have to pass filenames or explicit numbers (but this makes sense, as there is no MATLAB workspace in the first place). This implies that in order to keep a cumulative set of output from your program you would probably have to store those in a file. This might not be so painful: opening a file to append the next set of data is straightforward (I don't know about issues such as efficiency, and anyway this all depends on how much data and how many runs of your function we're talking about).